# Are storm drains put after road has been finished and asphalted?

Tags: roadway

Local government has been doing main capital city road reconstruction for a year now (had to be done in 3 month originally, but it is out of budget and out of time as usual).

They have finally opened it few month ago.
But now they are closing it down again, reason is to put down storm drains or drainage wells. As you can see from the photos, there is some major work being done.

We (vocal citizens) feel this stinks and either it was a trick to make money, or a stupid mistake. Non of these is great.

Government is claiming that this is how it is done. First you make a road, then you break it to put down drainage.

I googled around for road making timelapses, looked at various articles, but non had detailed this procedure. I would like to know if there is truth to this.

I wonder if there is a civil engineer out here, who has experience in these things and can shed light on the matter.

[image]

[image]

This youtube video clearly shows manhole is being put during asphaltation phase: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJFFY-8TV_E

Comment: Location will be useful here, as some places have better ideas than others...

Comment: @SolarMike This is capital of Georgia, Tbilisi.

Answer (score 1):

Most civil engineering jobs in the countries I have lived in are planned in a logical order, basically deep stuff - like provision for drains, then the foundations necessary and further pipes, drains etc then final surface and drain covers.

This means the time frame and costs are kept to a minimum - but it's expensive work.

Of course, some things have to be adjusted for, but even when councils are planning work on main roads they will check with Gas, Electricity and Water companies to see if they have work to be done as well to be able to combine the work and reduce the overall time. However, the ordinary motorist has a deep-seated hatred of cones and temporary traffic lights...

Comment: I see. It all makes sense but still doesn't answer my question. Is aslphalt layer broken (like you see on the photos) to put drains after road has been "finished".

Comment: @sandrodz I answer your question as given in the title.

Comment: In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYa6weDU-NY I see that manhole is put while aslphat is being put.